# How to make std::map compare to work on multiple data types?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

I've a entire table stored in `std::deque<record *>` and I need to allow the user to sort the table on any column. The table is presented to the user in a list box format.

Each record consists of multiple strings (struct of strings). However, the fields are of different types i.e., time (HH:MM:SS), float, and strings, even though they are all stored as strings.

The user is permitted to sort on any of these columns. When the user clicks on the column, I store each record in a multimap so that the table is shown in sorted format to the user.

However, since the columns are of different types, how do I write a single compare method, that handles all these efficiently?

I thought of the following ways

1. Use different maps for each type and write one compare function class for each of the maps.
2. Use a single map, with a compare class that handles all three different types. But for each insertion, the comparison class has to decide the type , and insert accordingly.

Is there a better way than these two?

Example:

```
struct ltDataCompare
{

    bool operator()( const CString& csData1, const CString& csData2)  const
    {

        if ( isTimeFormat(csData1) && isTimeFormat(csData1) )
        {
               // Do time relevant comparision
            }
            else if ( isNumberFormat( csTime1 ) && isNumberFormat(csTime2) )
        {
            double dPrice1 = atof((LPCTSTR)csTime1);
            double dPrice2 = atof((LPCTSTR)csTime2);

            return ( dPrice1 < dPrice2);
        }
        return ( csTime1 < csTime2 );
    }
};

std::multimap<CString,list_record_t*,ltDataCompare> _mapAllRecords; // Used only for sorting
```

Comment: What are you comparing?  Does it makes sense to compare a float to a string, for example?  Edit: sorry, I see what you mean.  You want to sort on one or more fields in the record.  Well, you can do that with a field enum which you pass into your sort function (or lambda), then use the appropriate value in the comparison function depending on the enum value.

Comment: Could you please shown an example Robinson?

Comment: Robinson, all fields are stored as strings. I need to determine the type of the field and do appropriate sorting/comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You can't re-sort a `map` or `multimap` - once an item is inserted, its position is locked. It would be better to use a different container such as a `vector` and sort it when necessary.

The nice thing about a comparison class is that it is allowed to contain state. You can have a member with some constant or pointer to determine which comparison method to use.

You can use the same principle to choose which field to sort on.

```
struct ltDataCompare 
{
    ltDataCompare(int field, int method) : m_field(field), m_method(method) {}
    bool operator()( const record& left, const record& right) const 
    {
        if (m_method == enumTimeFormat)
            return CompareTimes(left[m_field], right[m_field]);
        else if (m_method == enumNumberFormat)
            return CompareNumbers(left[m_field], right[m_field]);
        // ...
    }
    int m_field;
    int m_method;
};

std::sort(table.begin(), table.end(), ltDataCompare(0, enumTimeFormat));
```

Comment: Mark, I understand map cannot be resorted. I use maps/multimap, only to keep the records in order. Once these are sorted, then I don't need the map/multimap. I can destroy them. Could you show an example / link?

Comment: Could you show an example / link for "You can use the same principle to choose which field to sort on".

Comment: @user373215 : If you're only using them to sort, use a regular container (e.g. `std::vector<>` or `std::deque<>`) + `std::sort` and ditch the associative containers altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You could be more elegant about it - I don't know you'd save yourself any work - if you had a class with a < operator in it for each of the types.  If you have a superclass that has a virtual < operator then you can use it as the key type, as in

```
std::multimap< superclass, list_record_t >
```

Now you can use any of the child types as the actual keys (so long as you remain consistent).
Actually I'm not sure whether this is more clever or more elegant.  More clever is generally a bad thing (as it means more obscure/less maintainable).  If it makes for fewer lines of code, that's usually a good thing.